# How to array a simple model vertically and be able to use nodes and edges?

Tags: modeling, python, modifiers

I am trying to use Blender to model a building that repeats over 30 stories. I want to use this repetition to my advantage and use maybe a tool such as Array (My AutoCAD terms into Blender) to only adjust the first floor and have the rest of the 29 arrayed stories adjusted accordingly. Is this something that can be done? Also, by arraying the floor vertically (Z-Axis), how can I access the edges and nodes individually to export coordinates and connections?

The image below shows the current state of the file.

I need to export a lot of data from Blender with scripting, so access to all nodes is important. I would like to think that it is possible to somehow repeat one storey over multiple times.

Thank you.

[image: Two Stories for building]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array modifier.

[image]

In order to get all data, you can copy object in python and apply modifier on copy.